# Does the expression "press the flesh" imply hypocrisy?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, urban

I read in Longman the meaning of this phrase "to shake hands with many people while campaigning for public office". Is this phrase implying that the act of "pressing the flesh"/shaking hands "**hypocritical**" in the political language of the US?

Comment: No, it need not be seen as hypocritical.  A politician may think it is useful to her constituents if she meets them in person.

Comment: It doesn't imply any particular degree of hypocrisy.

Comment: As a US citizen, I can say that I do not regard this expression as intimating hypocrisy, but the simple political reality that if one wants votes, one must invest time and effort interacting with the public. "Pressing the flesh" is not substantive, but it is necessary. It can be used to indicate an activity one does not enjoy but that is needed for ultimate success.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: This question is on a par with asking whether "politician" implies "hypocrite".

Comment: @FF How can you tell when press-fleshing is hypocritical? _When the politician has just stressed the social distancing mantra._

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think so. It seems to be a legitimate question about whether such gladhanding is ever taken to be sincere. I'd say the current US president among several others (WJC comes to mind) are almost textbook cases of how some politicians really just thrive on such situations.

Comment: See, @EdwinAshworth has it precisely backwards: Biden's inability to help himself actually points towards the sincerity of his behavior with crowds (if not policies). His inability to reconcile that with advocating social distancing isn't necessarily hypocritical either: he could really believe that it's important to try to set a good example while being unable to help himself as a born pol.

Comment: Well... wait... I take it back. EA's "press-fleshing" **is** probably hypocritical, given how little respect *any*one has for the current media on either side. An easy proxy for how the press itself views the practice would be to tally the party of people they use the phrase around. If it leans heavy R, then, yeah, they're probably trying to imply sth untoward. If it's mixed or D heavy, it would just be a description of how retail politics is done.

Comment: Not necessarily hypocrisy, though that's within range; more like an artificial heartiness, a well-groomed bonhomie. Some people are just naturally good at pressing the flesh and enjoy it.